# Qt file gets reported as virus and won't launch

Tags: c++, qt4, antivirus

I have made a Qt file recently and just compiled it. Straight after compiling, my Avast antivirus blocks it as a virus. I have spent hours trying to find a syntax error/infinite loop/typing mistake. I have read other questions and googled the problem. I came to a conclusion that it is out of my understanding. Here are my files:

`top_secret.h`

```
#ifndef TOP_SECRET_H
#define TOP_SECRET_H

#include <QtGui>

class top_secret : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        top_secret();

    private slots:
        void password_ckeck();
        void go_to_page_1();
        void go_to_page_2();
        void go_to_page_3();
        void go_to_page_4();
        void quit();
        void lock();
        void about();

    private:
        QStackedWidget *book;

        QWidget *lock_window;
        QWidget *window1;
        QWidget *window2;
        QWidget *window3;
        QWidget *window4;

        QLineEdit *input;

        QAction *quit_action;
        QAction *lock_action;
        QAction *about_action;

        QMenu *fileMenu;
};
#endif
```

`submain.cpp`

```
#include "top_secret.h"

top_secret::top_secret(){
    //main things
    quit_action = new QAction(tr("Quit"), this);
    about_action = new QAction(tr("About"), this);
    lock_action = new QAction(tr("Lock"), this);

    connect(quit_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(about_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(about()));
    connect(lock_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(lock()));

    fileMenu = menuBar() -> addMenu(tr("File"));
    fileMenu -> addAction(lock_action);
    fileMenu -> addAction(about_action);
    fileMenu -> addSeparator();
    fileMenu -> addAction(quit_action);

    book = new QStackedWidget;

    //lock window
    lock_window = new QWidget;

    QLabel *label = new QLabel(tr("Enter password"));
    input = new QLineEdit;
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(tr("Go"));

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(password_ckeck()));

    QHBoxLayout *lock_layout;
    lock_layout -> addWidget(label);
    lock_layout -> addWidget(input);
    lock_layout -> addWidget(button);
    lock_window -> setLayout(lock_layout);

    //window 1
    window1 = new QWidget;
    QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("Name: Jakub Jagielski<br>Date of birth: 21/01/2014<br>Gender: Male<br>\
    Interested in: Women<br>Hair colour: Brown<br>Eye colour: brown");
    QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton(tr("Next"));

    connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(go_to_page_2()));

    QVBoxLayout *layout1;
    layout1 -> addWidget(label1);
    layout1 -> addWidget(button1);
    window1 -> setLayout(layout1);

    //window 2
    window2 = new QWidget;
    QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("Interests: Piano playing, science,<br>programming, computer science,<br>\
Xbox 360 playing, reading facts,<br>Logical puzzles, security programs,<br>bypassing self-made security \
programs,<br>creating complex security programs,<br>creating 2D games in Python tkinter,<br>creating apps \
like this one.");
    QPushButton *button2previous = new QPushButton("back");
    QPushButton *button2next = new QPushButton("next");

    connect(button2previous, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(go_to_page_1()));
    connect(button2next, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(go_to_page_3()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout2bottom;
    QVBoxLayout *layout2;
    layout2bottom -> addWidget(button2previous);
    layout2bottom -> addWidget(button2next);
    layout2 -> addWidget(label2);
    layout2 -> addLayout(layout2bottom);
    window2 -> setLayout(layout2);

    //window 3
    window3 = new QWidget;
    QLabel *label3 = new QLabel("Programming languages known by this user<br>rated out of 10:<br>\
    Python: 9/10<br>C++: 8/10<br>Java: 5/10<br>HTML/Css/JavaScript: 8/10<br>PHP: 2/10<br>Batch: 5/10<br>");
    QPushButton *button3previous = new QPushButton("back");
    QPushButton *button3next = new QPushButton("next");

    connect(button3previous, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(go_to_page_2()));
    connect(button3next, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(go_to_page_4()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout3bottom;
    QVBoxLayout *layout3;
    layout3bottom -> addWidget(button3previous);
    layout3bottom -> addWidget(button3next);
    layout3 -> addWidget(label3);
    layout3 -> addLayout(layout3bottom);
    window3 -> setLayout(layout3);

    //window 4
    window4 = new QWidget;
    QLabel *label4 = new QLabel("This app has only been created <br> to try to make an app with<br>\
    C++ and its wonderful library called Qt.<br>This person's account hasn't been<br>really hacked. In \
    fact, the person<br>has made this app himself.");
    QPushButton *button4previous = new QPushButton("back");
    QPushButton *button4end = new QPushButton("quit");

    connect(button4previous, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(go_to_page_3()));
    connect(button4end, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()));

    QHBoxLayout *layout4bottom;
    QVBoxLayout *layout4;
    layout4bottom -> addWidget(button4previous);
    layout4bottom -> addWidget(button4end);
    layout4 -> addWidget(label4);
    layout4 -> addLayout(layout4bottom);
    window4 -> setLayout(layout4);

    //main
    book -> addWidget(lock_window);
    book -> addWidget(window1);
    book -> addWidget(window2);
    book -> addWidget(window3);
    book -> addWidget(window4);

    setCentralWidget(book);
}

void top_secret::password_ckeck(){
    QString attempt = input -> text();
    if (attempt == "Jakub"){
        top_secret::book -> setCurrentIndex(1);
    }
}

void top_secret::go_to_page_1(){
    top_secret::book -> setCurrentIndex(1);
}

void top_secret::go_to_page_2(){
    top_secret::book -> setCurrentIndex(2);
}

void top_secret::go_to_page_3(){
    top_secret::book -> setCurrentIndex(3);
}

void top_secret::go_to_page_4(){
    top_secret::book -> setCurrentIndex(4);
}

void top_secret::lock(){
    top_secret::book -> setCurrentIndex(0);
}

void top_secret::quit(){
    QMessageBox messagebox;
    messagebox.setText("Do you really wish to quit?");
    messagebox.setWindowTitle("exit?");
    messagebox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    if (messagebox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes){
        close();
    }
}

void top_secret::about(){
    QMessageBox messagebox2;
    messagebox2.setText("This app is a test to try out my new C++ abilities. This app \
    would take me half the time it took me if I wrote it in Python.");
    messagebox2.setWindowTitle("About");
    messagebox2.exec();
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "top_secret.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    top_secret *program = new top_secret;
    program -> show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I'm very sorry about the amount of code present and I don't expect a perfect answer but if I could understand what I did wrong, I would be very pleased. Also, when I add the the file  to be ignored by my antivirus, it just doesn't launch.

Note that my other Qt programs work fine so I'm convinced that this is due to my code.

Comment: could it be that you are using the name `top_secret`? Also, you can set your AV to not scan that directory or executable.

Comment: i tried it with a different name and it remains the same. When i tell my antivirus to leave the file alone, it does. then the file simply doesn't launch (or no window pops up).

Comment: ...maybe there is really a virus on your system which has infected your executable?

Comment: Linux is the ultimate virus remedy, so upgrade to linux and enjoy. Or uninstall Avast?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with avast. But it wasn't a Qt specific thing. Avast blocked everything I programmed.

You just have to go to the settings and uncheck the box which says something like "unknown source". Avast doesn't know where your program comes from and blocks it because it may be a virus. At least that's what avast did with my programs. After I unchecked that checkbox everything worked fine.

Comment: The new SmartScreen behavior that ships with Windows 8 is very similar.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen

Comment: This is what I expected but is there something wrong with my code since nothing happens when I double click it?

Comment: Everythings fine with your code. I don't think your anti virus program will look into your source code and check for bad words.

Comment: What I meant is that when it is compiled, it must somehow behave like a virus.